# Data Transfer Objects help minimize calls to remote objects?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I've read that one of primary reasons for using DTOs is to minimize roundtrips between Service Layer and remote front-ends. Minimizing roundtrips essentially means reducing the number of service method calls, which is done by transfering more data with each call.

a) But can't the reduction of roundtrips also be achieved by service methods having a lot of parameters?

b) Are DTOs able to reduce roundtrips even more than service methods with lots of parameters? If yes, how? If no, then I don't quite understand how would reducing the number of roundtrips be one of the primary reasons for using DTOs?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have any context, so maybe the author of what you read meant something else, but here's a scenario where DTOs can indeed reduce the number of roundtrips from the presentation layer to the service layer.

Suppose you have a page where you must list users, and for each user, display the number of answers posted by the user. And suppose your page lists 10 users.

If you don't use a DTO, you'll have to call a method to get the informations about the 10 users. The for each user, you'll have to call a second method to get the number of answers he posted. That makes 11 method calls.

If you use a DTO which holds the information to display about a user, as weel as his number of answers, you may call a single method to get the list of 10 users, and get all the information at once.

Note that returning the list of 10 users, each containing its list of answers posted is not an option, because you would load an insane amount of information (the 2453 answers of each users) just to display the number of answers.

Comment: 1) Perhaps a bit off-topic, but judging from your answer I gather that you use multiple types of DTOs for each domain entity class in the model? 2) "We don't have any context, so maybe the author of what you read meant something else" Don't know if it helps, but the author didn't offer any specific context, but instead just repeated  [Fowler's definition](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)

Comment: 1) yes: a DTO is often suited to one specific use-case, at least in this case. 2) even in Fowler's definition, I don't see how parameters help returning objects.

Comment: "even in Fowler's definition, I don't see how parameters help returning objects" Fowler wrote that we could use lots of parameters instead of DTOs. Unless if by "returning objects" you're referring to the return value of a service method?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what JB Nizet has mentioned in his answer, we have been using DTO's to reduce the amount of data transferred between client and the server. One such scenario is whne we need some referential data or lookup data. For e.g. if we have a readonly collection of Country displaying the list of countries in the view or some sort of front end, we need notpass the list of countries everytime. We can cache the collection and DTO can be used to pass only the selecetd value. The DTO can have country code like "US", "GB", "IND" ect or some unique numeric value which corrosponds to the coutry code. On the client side you can have a mapper which maps the code to the selected value of the UI widget like a dropdown list.